# SSL certification on C# service over TCP

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-services, certificate, x509

I have 2 server side (dummy) programs which creates a TCP server (TCPListener) and then tries to authenticate the server with X509 certificates (BeginAuthenticateAsServer).
The client program is ready.

The difference between the two server side program is that one of them is a simple console application while the other is a Windows service.

For some reason client can connect to the console application but not to the service. Design is the same in both program.

I'm using the following line to describe the certificate I will use:

```
serverCertificate = new X509Certificate( "C:\\Users\\Tom\\workspace\\ServerSSL.cer", "12345678" );
```

I think something is fishy about privilages with the service program but I could not figured out in the last couple of days. Of course, I have the `The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.` error. When I tried to search for answer as help, I got results in topics of IIS / webservices but I'm using a simple Windows 7 Pro.

May I ask your help?

Comment: A service usually runs under an account that cannot access your (Toms) user directory, pick a globally accessible location such as SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData

Comment: I tried it, but I got the same error. However, I'll keep this info in my mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `ServerSSL.cer` most likely contains only certificate, not the private key. That's what the error message tells you.

Try to find `pfx` or `p12` file. Or if you have separate file that contains private key (i.e. `.key`) you need to make a pfx (p12) file from both of them (.key and .cer). You could use [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/) or [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) to do that.

Comment: Yes, `cer` contains only certificate and `pfx` both certificate and private key. I have both. I have tried to load pfx file but I got the same error. I think something else is the problem, because everything works in my console application. The problem occurs when running the service application.

Comment: You need to use pfx. When you instantiate `X509Certificate` class check if `PrivateKey` property is set.

Comment: I had to use `X509Certificate2` for that which has a `HasPrivateKey` property. The result was true... Hm... Simply reading this property helped to establish SSL connection. Anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: It was thanks to the class. I missed it. `X509Certificate2` was the right class to use. It would have worked IMHO even without reading `HasPrivateKey`.